# how to Add the standard Analyzer in sitecore 6.5 so that stop word is not ignored

Tags: c#, sitecore, lucene.net

I have the following code when iam searching it searches with all the key words for 1.example : London 
     2.example : London Bridge

but when  i search by

example3 : in London Bridge

it does not return any results. and also my scores are not sorted. here my  am making search only in title and trying to sort by scores (highest to lowest)

following is my code to making search only in title and trying to sort by scores (highest to lowest)

```
public SearchResultCollection Search(string searchString, string ProgramCampusStage, out  Hits hitScores)
    {
         var searchIndex=Sitecore.Search.SearchManager.GetIndex(SearchIndexName);
        using (IndexSearchContext context = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext())
        {

          // get the search term
           string searchterm = searchString.ToLower().Trim();


        PhraseQuery completeQuery = new PhraseQuery();
        completeQuery.SetSlop(4);

        foreach (var s in searchterm.Split(' '))
        {
            completeQuery.Add(new Term("title", s));
        }


        hitScores = context.Searcher.Search(completeQuery, new Sort(new SortField[1] { SortField.FIELD_SCORE }));
        SearchHits hits = new SearchHits(hitScores);
        var results = hits.FetchResults(0, Int32.MaxValue);

           foreach (var result in results)
            {
                try
                {
                    Item item = result.GetObject<Item>();
                    bool isAuthorized = UserUtility.IsUserAuthorized(item, ProgramCampusStage);
                    if (isAuthorized)
                    {
                        if (item != null)
                        {
                            string categoryName = GetCategoryName(item);

                            if (item.Language.Name != Context.Language.Name || categoryName == string.Empty)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            results.AddResultToCategory(result, categoryName);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            results.AddResultToCategory(result, OtherCategory);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return _searchResults = results;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using a `PhraseQuery` for your search, is that what you actually intended to do? Does the exact phrase "in London Bridge" exist in what is being indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the stop words as terms in your index (which could cause you other headaches like 'too many clauses' exceptions), you could try filtering out the stop words when you construct your query:

```
foreach (var s in searchterm.Split(' '))
{
  if (!Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET.Contains(s))
  {
     completeQuery.Add(new Term("title", s));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Not quite what I wanted but best answer, so I'll accept it